# Another take on the down-vote, no comment problem

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, down-votes

Yes, moderators, I already know that this question has been posted a number of times, the first one of which I came across was asked some 8 years ago and yet 
 this seems to still be a problem. I wish to bring it up yet again to see if anyone can answer my point of view on this problem...and answer reasonably without succumbing to jerk-hood or other down-votable nonsense.

I'm asking this question mainly because I posed a question asking for some help in building (compiling in my environment) an open source library. My current configuration does not allow me to do so and I don't know why. The question is reasonable and I'm NOT a newbie, I've been writing software for over 40 (yeah, forty) years so I do have a clue. The company I work for also seems to think I have a clue as they pay me a very nice six figure salary. My ability with software isn't in question here, the reason for the asinine response to my question is. What I expected was a link to a documentation site that I might have missed or a request for clarification or even perhaps an answer like "did you include such and such a library?" or something reasonable in response.

What I received was 3 down-votes which cost me 6 points of rep on the QUESTION ITSELF with NO explanation. I further conclude that this was done out of spite because the times on all three down-votes is within a minute of each other, two in the same minute. I came here to search out why comments on down-votes are not required. What I found was rather disheartening.

I'll be the first to admit, I did not read all the comments of all the answers for my search on why people are allowed to be vicious without consequence. TLDR indeed. BUT, I did take time to scan through to get the gist of the answers and this is what I concluded:

1. The predominant attitude seems to be "grow a thicker skin". Not helpful.
2. It seems that the prevailing attitude is "it won't hurt your reputation that 
   much, everyone can afford to lose a couple of points". Not reasonable.
3. "Why should I comment on something that is obviously `<insert viewpoint>`".

In my case, I don't contribute to SO that much (and this is one of the biggest reasons - the no comment down vote) so my rep isn't that high, so NO I can't afford to lose points, especially to mere spite.

When I do answer questions, I give good answers that always get up-voted so the community out there must believe that I'm not clueless. And yes, this id was created solely to ask this question, I don't need all the flak I'm going to get against my "real" profile.

So, here is my proposal to fix this problem. It comes from an old Pagan belief in that what you do to others comes back on you many-fold (some say 3, some say 5, others other values - you get the point). 
So, if you decide to down-vote a question or an answer, you get a choice:

1. Comment your down-vote with a good explanation. This is the desired response 
   and is in keeping with the spirit of SO.
2. Down-vote with no comment, but YOU LOSE 10 TIMES THE REP POINTS OR 1% OF YOUR TOTAL REP POINTS whichever is GREATER for doing so. E.g. I lose 2, you lose 20 and yes, doing this can take you negative on your rep. It should cost and cost mightily for being a jerk.
3. I, as the QUESTIONER, AM ALLOWED TO REVIEW YOUR COMMENTS and can reject your down-vote and recover my rep points so long as I answer your down-vote with comments of my own - no penalty to me for rejecting your down-vote. Moderator then gets to approve/reject the rejection. All comments to be public, of course.
4. It would be even nicer if I could get the user id of the down-voter and report their activity to a moderator for review. A nice "Spiteful" button on a comment or answer rather than just an up- or down-vote, but that's probably asking for too much. The trouble with allowing interaction between folks is that someone usually has to act as the babysitter.

It won't completely solve the problem but it will take the ability to simply be vicious down to a level that is like any other good compromise - EVERYONE pays for their actions.

Now, some of you might be wondering as to the harshness of my solution. Here it is: The gist of what I learned reading the other questions and comments is that everyone was looking at it from the point of view of the person answering, e.g. "I don't need to comment on stupid questions, I can just down-vote them because...". Really? Or "This question/answer is really obvious/useless/off-topic, I'm going to down-vote it because it's plainly obvious/useless/off-topic ...", that's some ego you have there, or "Some questions are just too `<insert descriptive phrase>` to comment on", etc. etc. etc. The point here is ***THAT IT ISN'T ABOUT YOU, IT'S ABOUT THE PERSON THAT ASKED THE QUESTION!***.

THAT person may have a perfectly legitimate reason for asking their question. However, in ALL CASES, that person DESERVES a REASONABLE ANSWER. Perhaps they *are* clueless, WHAT DOES IT MATTER? HELP THEM OUT! If the question is a "Do my homework for me" question, SO WHAT! They will pay the price for doing so later and, maybe, just maybe, they'll learn something because you...wait for it...HELPED THEM OUT.

And here is a biggie: The ONLY reason to down-vote a QUESTION is if the question itself contains bad information. EVEN THEN, COMMENT AND LET THE PERSON KNOW WHY YOU THINK IT'S BAD INFORMATION! It is my opinion that questions should only receive up-votes because of their pertinence, nothing else. No down-votes at all, if it isn't a good question, it won't show up in the result set at as high a level as another that has been up-voted. So much the better.

And do notice, I said QUESTION, NOT ANSWER there - my recent experience is with a QUESTION that I posed, NOT even an answer I gave.

But, the same goes for answers. If you are going to down-vote an answer, EXPLAIN YOURSELF OR TAKE THE HIT FOR BEING AN UNINFORMATIVE JERK.

Because, folks, at the end of the day, SO is about ANSWERING QUESTIONS, not displaying egos, rendering opinions on relative worthiness or anything else that has to do with the answers or the person answering. To paraphrase Joe Friday, Just The Answers, Ma'am.

It seems that even some of the moderators have inflated opinions of themselves such that they have forgotten the reason that SO was created. I have seen some mighty high-handed responses on a routine basis, worse because the moderator might have closed or ill-commented the question, BUT THE ANSWER THAT I NEEDED WAS PRESENT WITH THE QUESTION. Ooops, looks like someone got a little egotistical and reached out to slap someone just because they could rather than because they should.

We shall see if that happens here, too.

Comment: Is there something broken with your Shift key?

Comment: A shame you didn't link to the question, as we can't really know the circumstances. Is it possible that the question was not, in fact, as clear as you think it was? Did it contain any details that would help others figure out what the issue may be?

Comment: _"It should cost and cost mightily for being a jerk."_ Rude speak, strange attitude of yours.

Comment: Yet again, someone not really understanding what a downvote means.  For someone who purports to write good answers, you seem to lack a basic understanding of what voting is fundamentally about.  Turn it around; what if upvoting is treated to the **exact same** process?  All of a sudden, rep inflation becomes a massive thing.  Point is, downvotes are *specifically* against the question, not the person, and act as signal to other readers.  They are not for the poster.  They are for the *community*.

Comment: -1 because no one "deserves" answers to the questions they *ask* — the SE network of sites is primarily for *searchers*, not askers, to benefit from. I don't know you from Adam and I have not the slightest personal animus; I just think this suggestion is founded on fundamentally erroneous (if understandable) assumptions.

Comment: @fbueckert - I don't target up votes because it _is_ legit to have a short-hand version of "me too". If it's a good answer and it solves the stated problem, there isn't a need to elaborate unless there are additional details that would contribute to the answer. The community can judge a good answer or bad from the votes. A bad answer needs an explanation as to _why it's bad_ so that the community knows _why_ to avoid that answer or even the question. Just down voting leaves the casual viewer with an incomplete perception - it's bad and no one cares _why_. This ends up being a punishment.

Comment: Nope.  We do care why.  We just care about the long term effects **more**.  That, over everything else, is what drives SE.  Learn what downvotes are all about before deciding your interpretation is correct.  Ask a question in good faith, and you'll get a good reception.  Ask one that's more rant and accusations than actual question, and you'll find that no one is all that receptive to it.

Comment: @Nathan - didn't say they deserve an answer, I did say that if there is a negative aspect to the question or answer, THAT deserves comments. And I disagree (politely) with your stance. There is _no difference_ between the "questioner" and zero or more "searchers". The questioner _is the first searcher_ and is seeking the same thing that all the other searchers are searching for - an answer. So, if a question is bad, how do I fix it without knowing _how it's bad_? After all, I'm going to come back and search for this, what does a 20 down vote with no explanation tell me? _Nothing_!

Comment: It's not supposed to tell you anything, beyond that there's a problem with your question.  The tool tip states, "This question does not show research effort, or is not useful."  That's it, that's all.  Downvotes are primarily for **future readers**, to signal to them that this question isn't worth their time.

Comment: @Mick _"... how do I fix it without knowing how it's bad?"_ Did you ever bother to read the material available in the help center, how a good question is expected to look like?

Comment: @fbuekert - One more time I'll try to explain this. It isn't about the down votes themselves. It's about the why that goes with it. If this about supporting the community, then a fundamental pillar of that support is knowledge. How am I to know why an answer is bad or a question is bad if there is nothing attached to it, just the bare number? My "rant" as you call it is about the lack of knowledge that comes with an un-commented down vote. If the idea is to make knowledge available to the searcher, it needs to be good knowledge, not just _"this is bad - see the number"?_ knowledge.

Comment: I understand your stance perfectly.  And it highlights *a fundamental misunderstanding of what SE is about*.  It's not about you.  It's not about me.  It's not about the votes.  It's about building a respository of high quality knowledge.  The people are the way it happens, but are not the focus of the process in any sense.  Votes are the way we signal what is and isn't good.  **That** takes precedence over your hurt feelings.  Yeah, downvotes suck, and it's hard to be objective over them.  It doesn't change the fact that *they are not personal*.

Comment: What happens if an explanation already exists? It's not uncommon for people to simply ignore helpful comments, and refuse to fix their questions. Why should I be forced to add the same explanation to be able to downvote?

Comment: @Mick You're grown up, no? So we expect grown ups to [get informed](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) by themselves at Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And there's even more material you can check your question against. We won't repeat all of that with every downvote applied to a question. Don't tell me you can't know why a question is bad.

Comment: @fbuekert - Man, you _really_ are missing the point. My "hurt feelings" don't matter a bit here, as a matter of fact, the only "hurt" here is the lack of knowledge that comes from the down votes _with no explanation_. That is frustrating because I can't contribute to the community with good answers _if I can't fix what's broken in the question because I don't know what's broken_. You said it yourself - it's about building a high quality repository of knowledge. Part of that comes with the questions and their relative worth. How to judge and repair if there is no guidance?

Comment: @yannis - that's what the moderators do - "This question may be a duplicate". OK - _knowledge provided_. I know now that there might be a duplicate I missed in my search. It's all about the comments!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - "Don't tell me you can't know why a question is bad" - sure I can. You have to have the full context of the situation, which I didn't provide because it isn't necessary for this discussion. It _is_ possible to ask a bad question under the correct circumstances. People make assumptions, their focus may be different, they may not understand the context of their own question as well as some of the people that are viewing it or perhaps they didn't read the link. And I thought that personal attacks were forbidden. "grown up" indeed. Pot, kettle, color choice.

Comment: @Mick How on earth is considering you as a _grown up peer_ a _personal attack_ please??

Comment: @yannis - also, _yes_ you should provide the same information with your down vote. "Me too" doesn't help. If someone has already stated that this might be a duplicate, OK knowledge provided. _You_ don't need to "me too" that, do you? No, didn't think so, that's just mean. Got a different reason for down voting, fine! PROVIDE IT! If the folks that posted the question _ignore the responses_ well, that's not on you, that's _on them_. Their bad. You still have the moral high ground _because you tried your best to help_. Win for you, win .for the rest of the community.

Comment: Everyone gets the same message from a downvote; "This question does not show research effort, or is not useful." There you go. That's as specific as you get. Everything else is, and always will be, **optional**. If you want more, try asking in good faith, without the ranting and curation hostile suggestions. Oh, and try spelling my username right.

Comment: As a final thought, allow me to ask this: If I put up a question like "Is President Trump doing a great job" and 50 Democrats go in and down vote it with no explanation, what does that negative 50 tell me? Does it tell me that "no, he isn't", does it tell me that "the question is incomplete", does it tell me "we hate Trump"? That's my point. Just the number doesn't tell me or anyone else anything useful. If I'm searching for an answer I might discount something simply because of the negative votes, even though that answer might be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, that question will be closed, because it is an opinionated question, without basis for objectivity. It gets down votes because it isn't really a question. Not the way we classify them. And the number of down votes tells you just how many people believe its not a good question, and that future readers should ignore it. Which is their entire purpose.

Comment: @fbueckert - er, hate to contradict, but on this particular question, _there were **NO** comments, not even the aforementioned "this question does not show research effort, or is not useful"_. When I said _no_ comments, I meant _no_ comments. There is NOTHING to indicate why the question was down-voted. Even the above would have been useful, I could work with that. There was **nothing** to indicate why the down vote. There is nothing there save the question itself and the negative number. Nothing at all.Does that help clarify?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" is the tooltip on the downvote arrow @Mick.

Comment: @fbueckert - I understand the context of the "Trump" question would prevent it from being asked, I'm trying to step out of the "tech" world and present a situation that everyone can relate to. Ignore the context and consider the responses. The point is that I would not know _why_ it was down-voted. That's all. Was it personal opinion, was is lack of clarity in the question, was it because the actual question was answered with a "No". I don't know from the number itself. There is no context for the down-vote.

Comment: @Mick And finally a required comment for downvotes would end up in noise like: _gzugzuigzuggip8 t67t6vigobhz9c0cz9fg89vz789v_

Comment: @fbueckert - OK, that's great if **I** down-vote something, but it doesn't tell me, the questioner, why it was down voted. Tells you, the down-voter maybe, but doesn't tell **me** that! And am I to trust that the "default" of the "...not useful" is what the down voter intended? Again, I don't know. Could be, could be just spite, could be a number of things. I just _don't know_!

Comment: If down voters want to, they can comment to elaborate. Beyond that, assume that's why.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - yeah, which is why I suggested the big hit for no comments and the ability to reject said comments. Put them before an arbitrator so to speak. I didn't say it was a perfect solution, and, if the community is oriented on commenting things like "lkjasd;ljsdl;jf", then that shows a flaw and an intent that someone is just doing a "me too" and is too lazy to explain why. An alternate fix would be to provide a way of telling the reader why a "me too" was added. Knowing that 42 folks thought the question was useless would be good information to have.

Comment: @Mick Being able to signal to the wider community that a question is probably not worth their time is far more valuable than trying to help a single individual fix their question. We are all volunteering our time here, and our time is much better spent answering thoroughly researched on topic questions than trying (and very often failing) to help people understand why their questions don't fit the community's guidelines (which more often than not are obvious if you bother reading through the help center before posting).

Comment: @Mick So we would allow the asker of the question to _moderate_ everything by themselves? Would be a good idea for traffic control: _"Ha, officer I'm rejecting your fine, troll away from me."_

Comment: @fbueckert - ...and we all know what "assume" means. I maintain my stance that community members should be held accountable for their actions. If you're going to participate, then _participate_. "Me too" is just lazy and unproductive. Matter of fact, seems to me that that is one of the moderator options - something along the lines of "this is a me too answer and is cluttering the answer set". Don't remember the particulars but do remember the gist.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - not what I was saying at all, although it seems to work pretty well for Wikipedia...

Comment: @yannis At least I've established a stock comment for this: _"Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here."_ I (need to) use that quite frequently.

Comment: I vehemently disagree, and believe you lack a full understanding of the premise of SE, therefore your argument is predicated on a faulty assumption. And it just gets worse from there. At this point, I am no longer willing to engage. You want to destroy the very community that makes SE great. And that I oppose wholeheartedly.

Comment: @Mick Wikipedia? You can't be serious. It is well known for it's bad and abusive moderation practices.

Comment: @yannis - I think this is the fundamental difference in outlook - I see no difference between the person asking the question and the larger community - they are the same to me. All are seeking answers to what they don't know. However, there is one other point that I'll try to make and that is this - you _have to know_ that you are in SO to begin with. I have seen more than one site offer "support" by taking you directly to an edit screen in SO. The casual user may not even be aware that that is what happened, they might just ask their question as if targeting a single person.

Comment: @fbueckert - and I vehemently disagree with your statement that I want to destroy that community. I do not in any way, shape or form. But I can certainly now see the flaw in your thinking. And yes, we're done here.

Comment: We can't control what sites outside the SE network do @Mick. Nevertheless, Stack Overflow isn't a big textarea where you can just post whatever you want. Once you arrive at the site you are asked to register an account _and_ review the community's guidelines _before_ posting your first question. Furthermore, a fair amount of help material is available to all users, and in most cases is more than enough. You are, of course, free to ignore all that, but you don't get to claim ignorance or demand further explanation when the community rejects your question.

Comment: "when that shows a flaw and an intent that someone is just doing a "me too" and is too lazy to explain why." - This comes from somebody who does not review other people's questions in the review queue.  After 20-30 reviews, sometimes you don't feel like telling the person who asked a question about a software recommendation, the samething that is indicated in the help center.  As other people pointed out, without your question to understand, we really cannot accurately comment on the downvotes you received.  Votes are not personally, they are about the content, and the content itself.

Comment: "I, as the QUESTIONER, AM ALLOWED TO REVIEW YOUR COMMENTS and can reject your down vote and recover my rep points so long as I answer your down vote with comments of my own" - Does this mean you get to reject the "possible duplicate" comment also?  If I am able to find a duplicate, in the list of related questions, I don't typically find the question helpful......Which means I normally issue a downvote, after I issue a close vote, but that's just me personally.

Comment: "If the question is a "Do my homework for me" question, SO WHAT!" - This type of question, isn't on topic at Stackoverflow, so that's reason it should be closed.

Comment: "The point here is THAT IT ISN'T ABOUT YOU, IT'S ABOUT THE PERSON THAT ASKED THE QUESTION!." - Actually it isn't about the author of the question, it's about how helpful the question is to the community as a whole, and if that question can generate a quality answer.  **Good questions result in excellent answers.**  Poor questions result in poor answers.

Answer (score 19):

I am vehemently opposed to this suggestion. It destroys the basic premise that SE is built upon; that content is curated, and high quality posts rise to the top. By punishing those engaging in curation activities, all that will happen is that people will stop engaging in those activities, which will skew votes greatly upwards.

Comments are not required, and will not be, because people don't down vote enough as is. By placing another barrier in the way of voters, less people will vote, and it will slowly (or quickly, depending on the harshness of the penalty) destroy the community's willingness to actually engage and curate content. And then we become Quora.

So, no. This should not happen.

Answer (score 15):

This is the thing you've misunderstood: Your statement,

> The point here is THAT IT ISN'T ABOUT YOU, IT'S ABOUT THE PERSON THAT ASKED THE QUESTION!.

Is wrong - or at least incomplete.  One of the critical functions of downvotes is to tell *other people* (not the OP) what the community thinks of a question or answer.  A negative score on a question tells other people that the community doesn't think it's a very good question.

Comment: I don't mind a down vote, _so long as it's a legit reason_ and the only way I know it's legit is to...wait for it...READ THE COMMENT! I have no problem at all with fixing something but I have to know what to fix. A simple down vote does not tell me anything and I couldn't care two spits about the rest of the community and their take on the question or the answer for that matter, _I_ posted the question, _I'm_ the one that cares about the answer. In No Case is it appropriate to take a negative stance without explaining why. It's not helpful to anyone and, worse can cause unintended side affects

Comment: @Mick: And yeah, there we go. The SE communities value their common benefit more (*much* more) than the benefit to any one asker, and are more than happy for the software design to reflect this fundamental value by making downvotes relatively easy to use so that the community can benefit from good scoring, even if askers are at times irritated or inconvenienced.

Comment: @Mick If you want to learn what might need fixing about your question, you might consider asking a Meta question about the question itself, rather than jumping to the conclusion your question is perfect, and the community is the problem. Just a thought.

Comment: I don't _presume_ anything when I ask a question. I asked the question because I want an answer. I don't have a viewpoint on it's relative level of correctness, all I know is that I have a question and have phrased it the best I know how _at that moment_. If there are perceived problems with the question, the perception belongs to folks _other than me_. As such, how can I ask a question about fixing something that _I don't think is broken to begin with_? In short, how do I know about what I don't know? The case I'm speaking of that generated this post did, finally receive a good comment.

Comment: @Alex - continued. And I fixed the question because the stated deficiencies were something I agreed with in retrospect. I didn't see it to begin with and the circumstances were rather unique concerning the target of the question. _But I wouldn't have know that without the very helpful comments provided._.

Comment: @Mick Loads of people have asked Meta questions looking for help improving their question, without knowing what is wrong (hence the question asking what is wrong). Such questions asked in good-faith are generally well received.

Comment: @Mick _"I asked the question because I want an answer."_ And you call other people volunteering here _egocentric_? Seriously??

Comment: @Mick: I do have sympathy for people looking for actionable feedback on how to fix their questions, and I think there are ways SE could improve on that (in particular, predefined lists of anonymous reasons for the vote). I don't think it's worth sacrificing easy up- and down-votes to do so, though.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to assume a great deal of malice involved with downvotes in general.

> What I received was 3 down votes which cost me 6 points of rep on the QUESTION ITSELF with NO explanation. I further conclude that this was done out of spite because the times on all three down votes is within a minute of each other, two in the same minute.

you seem to assume the votes were out of spite because of the time between them. there is almost 7 million users on SO, while i'm not 100% sure on the number of those online at the time and with downvote privileges it is entirely possible that 3 users could have found you're question at the same time and downvoted it for different reasons. not knowing the timing of the first vote to when the question was posted keep in mind that some people can read really fast. the only time you should be suspicious for malicious voting is when within seconds all your questions/answers over the last view years get down voted when most weren't bumped by the Community user but there is a system in place which helps correct this

now about you're proposal

> 2. Down vote with no comment, but YOU LOSE 10 TIMES THE REP POINTS OR 1% OF YOUR TOTAL REP POINTS whichever is GREATER for doing so. e.g. I lose 2, you lose 20 and yes, doing this can take you negative on your rep. It should cost and cost mightily for being a jerk.

this becomes quite the hassle for users with more than 2,000 rep so those with more than 100k rep, who probably have the most experience on the site to know good and bad questions/answers, are going to loose 2k or more rep for making 1 downvote for not wanting to spam the same comment *"this shows no research"* or something that's already been commented

also Negative Rep isn't normally possible by the normal system. since you loose privileges when your rep drops bellow what is required for one. negative rep would mean [you can't use the site at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts), the only times there is negative rep is when there is a suspension (though we still see it as 1 rep but in reality is bellow 1). ofcause someone getting into negative rep with this suggestion would be impossible since you need [100 rep to downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) ([for 125 on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)) and at the least they will lose 20 rep

> 3. I, as the QUESTIONER, AM ALLOWED TO REVIEW YOUR COMMENTS and can reject your down vote and recover my rep points so long as I answer your down vote with comments of my own - no penalty to me for rejecting your down-vote. Moderator then gets to approve/reject the rejection. All comments to be public, of course.

this adds more work for the moderators who are in essence the exception handlers for a site when the community can do something. also i have seen cases of users posting obviously off-topic questions and arguing the point that it's a valid question despite evidence to the contrary (the off-topic reason with meta posts)

also you can ready in a way review comments and reject them to be removed as you can flag comments

> 4. It would be even nicer if I could get the user id of the down-voter and report their activity to a moderator for review. A nice "Spiteful" button on a comment or answer rather than just an up or down vote but that's probably asking for too much. The trouble with allowing interaction between folks is that someone usually has to act as the babysitter.

this is kinda redundant if they are almost forced to comment. also as you assume there is malice in all downvotes it would be rightfully so to assume that users will revenge downvote anyone who they knew downvoted their posts spamming the comment like *"ha ha ha ha ha ha you suck go die"* or garbage adding work for the user to then reject each comment and mods to then validate the rejection which again adds to what i just said about adding more work to the mods

---

> "This question/answer is really obvious/useless/off topic, I'm going to down vote it because it's plainly obvious/useless/off-topic ...", that's some ego you have there

while obviousness/uselessness could be different between each person how does *"This question/answer is really off topic, I'm going to down vote it because it's plainly off-topic"* have anything to do with ego? if there is evidence that the user knows that a kind of question is off-topic (the badge for going though the tour) and posts it anyway why not downvote it? you say earlier with your suggestion

> EVERYONE pays for their actions.

but this comment seems to only be targeting the voters, not the people who ask the question so then not EVERYONE is paying for their actions.

what if the question isn't a question at all but some petty user attacking a mod's actions? yes this did happen a couple of days ago on Movies and TV where a user kept creating accounts and using vulgar language effectively saying in one question [*"if [MOD] stops deleting my accounts i'll stop this abuse"*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GI3k.png). it's clearly not a useful question, it's not a question at all. where is the ego in me down voting that?

---

> The ONLY reason to down vote a QUESTION is if the question itself contains bad information. EVEN THEN, COMMENT AND LET THE PERSON KNOW WHY YOU THINK IT'S BAD INFORMATION!

you seems to be forgetting the 3 reasons that the hover text of the buttons say

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

take the following questions

- Stack Overflow - how do i output to the screen/page? | Tagged: php, c++, ruby, iphone, zombie-process
- Arqade - [dump of error log] | tagged: minecraft
- Stack Overflow - code wont work hfksjfdahkjfdhfdkjhfdskhfdskjhfdsk (no code posted)
- Stack Overflow - i have the following PHP Code which has a user send a command and there is a placeholder for when the command is sent [code posted]. how can i make my toaster receive these commands
- Stack Overflow - how do i connect to a database in PHP?

all 5 of these fall into one of the 3 reasons and you're suggestion would have the comments spammed with the same reason. now you might argue that the comments will only get posted if you approve them but what about users who post a question but do nothing to fix or answer comments already made currently? you have admitted yourself here that the account you used to post this question is not your actual one so what if you decided to just post this and return to your original account (which i highly suspect you did given the lone upvote though it's just as probable that it was someone else. but since you are assuming that no one has good intentions with a down vote why should we assume that there are good intentions with upvotes either?)

---

> Because, folks, at the end of the day, SO is about ANSWERING QUESTIONS, not displaying egos, rendering opinions on relative worthiness or anything else that has to do with the answers or the person answering.

while you are right in some parts you contradict yourself here. how can SO be about answering questions but not about anything else that has to do with the answer? Stack Overflow is about making library of detailed answers like what the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) says, so where is the detailed answer when it's a code dump that only works with the Asker's code and doesn't explain what the problem was and what was done to fix it? or a link which provides an answer but later is lost because of link rot?

> But, the same goes for answers. If you are going to down-vote an answer, EXPLAIN YOURSELF OR TAKE THE HIT FOR BEING AN UNINFORMATIVE JERK.

there is also hover text for the downvote button. while it just says:

> This answer is not useful

how useful is an answer with a dead link or an unexplained code dump, or even saying *"i have this problem to"* or *"thanks, this worked for me"*

---

> If the question is a "Do my homework for me" question, SO WHAT! They will pay the price for doing so later and, maybe, just maybe, they'll learn something because you...wait for it...HELPED THEM OUT.

the problem is when will they pay the price? when it comes to a programming exam where access to the internet is removed? when their employer finds out they have been paying someone to get someone else to do their work for free?

while there are different way of learning you can not deny that sometimes if you do someone else's work for them what they learn is reliance.

there was a student in my university programming class who i helped alot, probably to the point where i was telling them what to do (ie *"because you can only read the file one line at a time and you don't know how many lines are in a file you will need a while loop which will add each line to your variable and terminate if the end of the file is reached."*, *"because this is a text box a user could put in the word hello instead of the number you are expecting so you need an if statement to check for this and output an error if it's not a number"*). about a year or 2 later after i graduated they emailed me asking if i could do their assignment saying they couldn't understand it yet i wasn't the only person they emailed, they emailed everyone in the class (i had my university emails forward to my personal email at the time)

there is nothing wrong in giving a guiding hand but one of the things about Stack Overflow and any other Stack Exchange site is that you put in some effort to solve it on your own. this is the Research Effort the voting buttons talk about

---

Answer (score -3):

I agree that downvotes without comments are annoying, but I think that the approach you are suggesting is not the best approach to solving the problem, for the following reasons:

- If downvoters decides not to explain their downvote, giving them -20 reputation will make bad posts not have as many downvotes as would be ideal, which kind-of breaks the voting system
- If posters are allowed to remove downvotes if they disagree with the reason for the downvote on their post, many posters will remove the downvotes even if they are for legit reasons

We already penalize answer downvotes with a -1 rep to the downvoter.

I think a more reasonable approach would be permitting commentless downvotes on questions, but giving the downvoter a -1 repuation penalty similar to answers UNLESS one of the following is met:

- The downvoter has at least 3k reputation (matching the closevote privilege) at the time they make the downvote

  - I feel that experienced users should be afforded the privilege to decide for themselves whether their downvote deserves an explanation
- The downvoter leaves a comment on the question and has no deleted (excluding self-deleted) comments on the questions

  - This would allow meaningless/gibberish comments justifying downvotes to deleted, resulting in the reputation penalty being restored
  - This also prevents the downvoter from leaving another meaningless comment to recoup the penalty
- The question was closed at the time of the downvote
- The question is closed at the present time (i.e. you downvote the question, the question later gets closed, you get refunded unless and until it opens again)
- The downvoter flagged the question and the flag has not been declined

While this system may appear more complex than necessary, I feel that this would encourage users to explain their downvotes on questions while still allowing low-quality questions to be downvoted freely.

Comment: BTW, as an unrelated aside, `<li>`s go inside `<ul>`s, not the other way around.

Comment: That was me; I provided the correct markdown for a list.

Comment: However, even as nice as this suggestion is, it is still flawed, for one simple reason: you can't rely on popular opinion to always do the right thing; take [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question) for example; the right thing was the deletion of the answer.  If I had to provide a comment explaining my downvote of that answer, it would have been removed under your system.

Comment: This cure sounds worse than the illness.

Comment: Allow me to ensure clarity - I don't want a 20 point hit for _every_ downvote, _just the one's that don't bother to comment_. Regular down votes, with good explanations are perfectly welcome and necessary, even. It's the lack of information and the hit to my reputation, that may be UNJUSTIFIED IF THE DOWN-VOTER IS CLUELESS, that I object to. The current system allows strangers to punish someone without consequence. THAT is unacceptable. And a 1 point hit isn't good enough, nor appropriate for legit down votes. Only comment-less votes are targeted here and it should be COSTLY to do so.

Comment: @Mick Please STOP THAT UGLY YELLING all over! That doesn't make anything you write better justified and is considered rude.

Comment: Yes, the caps _are_ for making a point. Emphasis can be effected in a number of ways, CAPS GETS YOUR ATTENTION, doesn't it? That _is_ the point.

Comment: @Mick **use bold instead** by typing `**text you want to make bold**`, outputting **text you want to make bold**

Comment: @Mick Who's yelling is wrong, as the saying goes.